# how to delete elements from a list using del and indices

Tags: python, list, del

I have a list from which all 2s need to be deleted:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 8, 2]
```

I also have the index of all the 2s in L:

```
myIndex = [1, 3, 6]
```

How can I use `del` to remove all the 2s from L?

I've tried `del L[myIndex]` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `del` in a for loop ensuring that the indices are sorted in reversed order:

```
for i in sorted(myIndex, reverse=True):
    del L[i]
```

---

```
print(L)
[1, 3, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the indices become off-by-1 every time a deletions occurs and the list gets shorter. The more Pythonic approach is to collect everything that is still valid into a new list. This can be done with a simple list comprehension as follows:

```
L2 = [i for i in L if i != 2]

>>> L2
[1, 3, 4, 8]
```

Alternatively, you can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
L3 = list(filter(lambda x: x != 2, L))

>>> L3
[1, 3, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remove function to remove all the 2's elements.

```
for i in range(L.count(2)):
    L.remove(2)
```